# Ruby on Rails - Hide user_id in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I would like to hide the user_id in the URL if I can.

http://domain.com:3000/users/1

Here is the page info.

---

action: show
controller: users
id: '1'

Comment: What's the purpose? Do you just want to use a non-sequential identifier to avoid exposing "guessable" information? Or do you want to just access the current user's ID from the session and assume that if there's no ID you're referring to the current user? Or...?

Comment: I don't want people knowing how many subscribers I have. I got the answer below. Thanks.

Comment: Exposing an ID doesn't tell anybody how many users you have. Plus you can start from an arbitrary number, or use a GUID, or etc. There's a [gem for this](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id in the URL is required so that the controller/action knows which user it should display on the page. It shows the user with an id of 1 in this case, but in other cases, you might want to show the details of another user.

It is possible to substitute the `id` in the URL with other identifying information, for example `username`.

To do this, see http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url. You simply have to override the `to_param` method in your model.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Railscast that uses the friendly_id, a great gem that provides URL renaming:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

Answer (score 0):

To do this. In your user model make sure you have:

```
is_sluggable :whatever-attribute-you-want-to-mask-users/1
```

In your user controllers use:

```
@user = User.find_using_slug(params[:user])
```